# Wordpress + Gmaps = GreyBox

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I have problem with gmaps on my wordpress site.
I had picture of the map before but few days ago I started getting only grey box without map.

You can see it [here](http://grand.co.me/contact-us/).
How can I fix this problem?
Same theme, same plugins..but something changed probably because I don't see the map anymore.

Comment: Did you noticed the error in the console log?

Comment: Please share your map js and have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733510/gmap-api3-and-bootstrap-grey-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is forced by http://grand.co.me/wp-content/themes/porto/css/theme_1.css?ver=4.4.1 (line 2959)

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    /*height: auto;*/
    height: 100% !important;/*<--problem*/
    width: auto !important;

}
```

add this style to fix it:

```
.gm-style img {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Apart from that: the page has a size of 8KB, but you load about 1MB of CSS.
I've never seen a page which loads this amount of CSS

Comment: That's it, thank you!
How did you find this error?I looked at console but didn't find anything.

Comment: I've seen that the zoom-control looks crazy, so it was my first guess that it is a CSS-problem with `<img>`

Comment: Well..good find..thanks again.